# Collect values from JSON under conditions

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

I am working to collect values from JSON under conditions. The base data and expected data are below. I want to collect IDs with same to values of key1 and key2. Key of collected data is when key1 and key2 of each element is same, I want to get the values of each key. I am sorry for the confusing explanation.

I have to use this script at Google Apps Script. So please note I cannot use ECMAScript6.

**Base JSON**

```
var data = [
    {id: "id_A", key1: "value1", key2: "value2"},
    {id: "id_B", key1: "value2", key2: "value3"},
    {id: "id_C", key1: "value3", key2: "value4"},
    {id: "id_D", key1: "value2", key2: "value3"},
    {id: "id_E", key1: "value2", key2: "value3"},
    {id: "id_F", key1: "value3", key2: "value4"},
    {id: "id_G", key1: "value1", key2: "value2"},
    {id: "id_H", key1: "value4", key2: "value5"}
]
```

**Expected result**

```
var result = [
    {id: ["id_A", "id_G"], key: ["value1", "value2"]},
    {id: ["id_B", "id_D", "id_E"], key: ["value1", "value2", "value3"]},
    {id: ["id_C", "id_F"], key: ["value1", "value2", "value3", "value4"]},
    {id: ["id_H"], key: ["value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value5"]}
]
```

**My current script**

```
function convertJSON(){
  var json = [
      {id: "id_A", key1: "value1", key2: "value2"},
      {id: "id_B", key1: "value2", key2: "value3"},
      {id: "id_C", key1: "value3", key2: "value4"},
      {id: "id_D", key1: "value2", key2: "value3"},
      {id: "id_E", key1: "value2", key2: "value3"},
      {id: "id_F", key1: "value3", key2: "value4"},
      {id: "id_G", key1: "value1", key2: "value2"},
      {id: "id_H", key1: "value4", key2: "value5"}
  ];

  var sorted = json.sort(function(i, j){
    if (i.key1 < j.key1){
      return -1;
    }
    if (i.key1 > j.key1){
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  });

  var result = [];
  var id = [];
  var key = [];
  var key1 = "";
  var key2 = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++){ 
    if (i > 0) {
      if (key1 == sorted[i].key1 && key2 == sorted[i].key2){
        id.push(sorted[i].id);
        key.push(sorted[i].key1);
        key.push(sorted[i].key2);
      } else {
        var key = key.filter(function(e, i, ar) {
          return ar.indexOf(e) == i;
        });
        result.push({id: id, key: key});
        var id = [];
        var key = [];    
        var key1 = sorted[i].key1;
        var key2 = sorted[i].key2;
        id.push(sorted[i].id);
        key.push(sorted[i].key1);
        key.push(sorted[i].key2);
      }
    } else {
      var key1 = sorted[i].key1;
      var key2 = sorted[i].key2;
      id.push(sorted[i].id);
      key.push(sorted[i].key1);
      key.push(sorted[i].key2);
    }
  }
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

// result is
// [
//   {"id":["id_A","id_G"],"key":["value1","value2"]},
//   {"id":["id_B","id_D","id_E"],"key":["value2","value3"]},
//   {"id":["id_C","id_F"],"key":["value3","value4"]}
// ]
}
```

Thank you so much for your time and advices.

Comment: How id_H can be {id: ["id_H"], key: ["value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value5"]} `value1", "value2` is not in `id_H`

Comment: @brk Thank you for taking your time. For example, key1 and key2 of "id_A" have "value1" and "value2". So "key" of "id_B" which has "value2" and "value3" is "value1", "value2", "value3". "key" of "id_C" which has "value3", "value4" is "value1", "value2", "value3", "value4". So "key" of "id_H" which has "value4" and "value5" is "value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value5". When key1 and key2 of each element is same, they are linked. I'm sorry for the confusing explanation.

Comment: It is really confusing.Still now i dont get the logic of how `"key" of "id_B" which has "value2" and "value3" is "value1", "value2", "value3"`,how come `value1` come in the picture

Comment: @brk I'm really sorry for confusing you. For example, please imagine the stairs. When go up the stairs one by one step, the first step is "id_A". When go up from first to second steps, "id_A" has "value1" and "value2". "id_B" is required to go up from first to third steps. So "id_B" has "value1", "value2", "value3". By this trend, "id_H" has from "value1" to "value5".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this sample script? Please think of this as one of several answers. I think there are more effective methods. When I saw your question, at first, I thought of 3 parts. So I separated to 3 parts to retrieve the result.

1. Retrieve first and last steps.

   - Retrieved first and last steps are used as the reference points to analyze stairs.
2. Analize stairs.

   - Retrieve whole steps in order.
3. Summarize IDs and Keys.

I confirmed that this sample script works by GAS.

#### Sample script :

```js
var data = [
    {id: "id_A", key1: "value1", key2: "value2"},
    {id: "id_B", key1: "value2", key2: "value3"},
    {id: "id_C", key1: "value3", key2: "value4"},
    {id: "id_D", key1: "value2", key2: "value3"},
    {id: "id_E", key1: "value2", key2: "value3"},
    {id: "id_F", key1: "value3", key2: "value4"},
    {id: "id_G", key1: "value1", key2: "value2"},
    {id: "id_H", key1: "value4", key2: "value5"},
];

// 1. Retrieve first and last steps.
var firststep, laststep;
for (var i in data) {
  var chk1 = data[i].key1;
  var chk2 = data[i].key2;
  var f1 = true;
  var f2 = true;
  for (var j in data) {
    if (data[j].key2 == chk1) f1 = false;
    if (data[j].key1 == chk2) f2 = false;
  }
  if (f1) firststep = data[i];
  if (f2) laststep = data[i];
}

// 2. Analize stairs.
var stairs = [];
stairs.push(firststep);
var key1 = firststep.key1;
var key2 = firststep.key2;
while (key2 != laststep.key2) {
  var temp = {};
  for (var i in data) {
    if (data[i].key1 == key2) {
      if (!temp[data[i].key1]) {
        stairs.push(data[i]);
        temp[data[i].key1] = true;
      }
    }
  }
  key2 = stairs[stairs.length - 1].key2;
}

// 3. Summarize IDs and Keys.
var result = [];
var key = [];
for (var i in stairs) {
  var id = [];
  if (!~key.indexOf(stairs[i].key1)) key.push(stairs[i].key1);
  key.push(stairs[i].key2);
  for (var j in data) {
    if (data[j].key1 == stairs[i].key1 && data[j].key2 == stairs[i].key2) {
      id.push(data[j].id);
    }
  }
  result.push({id: id.slice(), key: key.slice()});
}

// When you use GAS, you can see the result at Stackdriver.
// Or please use Logger.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, "\t"))
console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, "\t"));
```

Is my understanding correct? If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I want to modify.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It worked fine. I can completely get my expected result.

Comment: @Elsa Welcome. Also I could study from your question. Thank you, too.